# Drupal isn't outputting site specific part of urls (for files)

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I'm about to take over and maintain a website built on Drupal. I have no real experience with Drupal since before, but so far on my local machine I'm trying to set up a development environment. I've managed to get Apache to run and return the PHP, stylesheets works etc.

But when it comes to certain images and files, they get broken urls. Looking the the site that is currently live, it seems I should get url's in the style of `www.example.com/sites/default/files/filename.ext` and so on, but instead I get `www.example.com//filename.ext`, like it doesn't understand how to build the url.

I can also not login to the site, at first I thought I was given the wrong password, but after generating a new password with the password script and updating the db, I still can't login (it does log the failed attempts in the db).

So my question is, is it possible that during my setup, I have missed something that allows Drupal to understand what site is actually being requested or such?

Here's basically what I've done:

- Import the database dump into MySQL
- Set up Apache with the needed modules
- Access it on localhost:5000

There hasn't been much else to it so far, and it almost works.. ;)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: check permissions of `sites/default/files/`

Comment: @coderodour thanks, but they seem ok, apache is running as my user. Also, if I type a full url to a file I know exists, Apache will serve it in the browser. So I don't think it's related to permissions in this case..

Comment: Go to Configuration -> Media -> Filesystem and make sure your `Public file system path` is set to `sites/default/files`?

Comment: I can't login either, so I can't do that (unsure if it is related, tried several accounts and resetting the password through the db)..

Comment: @coderodour you were right! I managed to log in using drush to generate a one off link, and the public file system path was empty! thanks! (I don't know how to approve your comment as an answer, perhaps not possible?)

Comment: I have posted my comment as an answer. You can accept it there. I am sure it will be helpful for future inquiries. Thank you for actually taking the initiative. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Configuration -> Media -> Filesystem and make sure your `Public file system path` is set to `sites/default/files`?